# Set line opacity in highchart line chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know you can set the opacity of a series line in highcharts by using a rgba colour value as a property for the series line colour (like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kesck/22/)) (`color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)'`), but is there a way to just set the opacity without affecting the colour used?

I want my chart to sick to using the global colours array and the number of series in my chart is variable.

Comment: You could access the global colors array (Highcharts.getOptions().colors), retrieve the color from there and covnert into the rgba form while adding the 'a'.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example of how this would be done?

Comment: Unfortunately this paraemter is not possible, only by 'rgba'.

Comment: Try giving custom opacity to `.highcharts-series-group {
            opacity: 0.25;
        }`

Answer (score 3):

To reiterate:
You could access the global colors array (Highcharts.getOptions().colors), retrieve the color from there and covnert into the rgba form while adding the 'a'.

For example:

```
var color = Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0];
var rgba = new Highcharts.Color(color).setOpacity(0.66).get();
```

Well, or split '#RRGGBB' yourself and put it back together.